# Choosing Conv2D filters value to start off with

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I realise that the following question may garner responses along the lines of "it's about experimenting and using experience" but I'm going to ask anyway because I think it would be useful to get an idea of what I should be looking to start off with.

In Keras, the `Conv2D` convolution layer, there's a parameter called `filters`, which I understand to be the "number of filter windows convolving on an image of a size defined by the `kernel_size` parameter". I.e. `Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3,3)..)` will mean 32 windows of size 3x3 will be scanning across an image.

My question is: if you are creating a brand new neural network to solve, let's say, an image classification/recognition problem without leveraging a pre-trained neural network (so starting from scratch), what `filters` value do you typically start off with for your first convolutional layer? Is there a rule of thumb? Is this just literally an experimentation answer?

Let's say I want a brand new model to be able to recognise whether or not there's a dog in an image without leveraging `ResNet50` or `InceptionV3` imagenet models, and I'm going to use coloured images of size 4160x3120 which I've scaled down to an `input_shape` of (224,168,3), what should my first `Conv2D` layer look like?

E.g. is this sample code a good starting point to solve my problem:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3,3), activation="relu", input_shape=(224,168,3), data_format="channels_last"))
model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3,3), activation="relu"))
#additional model design code
```

Is 32 a good starting point? Should I go smaller? Is doubling filters size from `Conv2D` layer to `Conv2D` layer an appropriate approach to solving a new problem?

Completely understand that this is an inherently complex subject and there's no "get rich quick" approach but I just want to get a better appreciation of the subject.

Comment: while this is entirely my opinion , going from 3 channels to 32 channels is too much and it is better if start slow .To answer your main question , while it is truly a matter of trial and error , a good rule of thumb I use is number of parameters , e.g your input has 224*168*3=112896 while your layer 1 has 221*165*32=1166880 which is massive increase , I usually try to keep the increments slightly smaller because training on your own , you can really do only so many epochs(please do correct my math if i am wrong )

Comment: @NiteyaShah thanks for your perspective on this. So, in your opinion, my first layer should look like `Conv2D(3, kernel_size=(3,3), activation="relu", input_shape=(224,168,3), data_format="channels_last"))` and go from there? Also, I'm a bit confused about how you derived 221*165?

Comment: Ah, you factored in the `kernel_size` and got 221*165. So if I set `filters` to 3, should I maintain the same `kernel_size` that I have currently set?

Comment: Setting it to 3 will be extremely redundant , keeping it in the range of 10 - 18 is would've been my choice with a couple of short runs to get the feel of the network if you can afford it , as for your second doubt it seems that your doubt is more theoretical , i suggest that you read up on why we go with conv in the first place and what is the role of the filters and a bit on convolution itself .

Comment: Also as a side note , it is good practice to train your network using square images , as sometimes you might recieve images from different sources with different image ratios and while resizing into a square will not hurt learning , resizing a odd rectangle into another can do it

Answer (score 1):

16 or 32 is fine.

The filters in the first few layers are usually less abstract and typically emulates edge detectors, blob detectors etc. You generally don't want too many filters applied to the input layer as there is only so much information extractable from the raw input layer. Most of the filters will be redundant if you add too many. You can check this by pruning (decrease number of filters until your performance metrics degrade)

The kernel size determines how much of the image you want affecting the output of your convolution (the 'receptive field' of the kernel). It's been seen smaller kernels are generally better than larger ones (i.e go with 3x3 instead of 5x5, 7x7).

The Inception Architecture takes these decisions out of the hand of the modeller as it lumps filters of different kernel size together and let the model learn the best ones to use.

As reference I would suggest going through Stanford's CS231n course on youtube to get a understanding of it all : https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLC1qU-LWwrF64f4QKQT-Vg5Wr4qEE1Zxk